Another inequality for Stirling numbers
While investigating numerically these inequalities, I have observed that the following (somewhat) simpler inequality involving Stirling numbers of the second kind $ {n\brace m}$ also seems to hold (for $n \ge m\gt 1$)
$$ {n\brace m} \gt  {n+1\brace m+1} \frac{n(-m^2+m+1)+2m^3-m^2-m}{n(m^2+m-1)-m^2+m}.$$
Obviously, it holds when $n\gt \frac{2m^3-m^2-m}{m^2-m-1} $ since then the right hand side is negative.
I would need help for the case when $m \ge 2$ and $n\le \frac{2m^3-m^2-m}{m^2-m-1}  $.
Actually, as soon as $m\ge 4$ the integral part of $\frac{2m^3-m^2-m}{m^2-m-1}$ is $2m+1$, then, after checking a finite number of cases corresponding to $m=2$ and $m=3$, we may assume $n \le 2m+1$.
